# Tensorflow Model Fit : AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype[float64]' object has no attribute 'is_floating'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, data-fitting

I develop a model using Tensorflow 2.9.1.

My inputs are like this :

```py
x = [...] # Array of 24 floats
y = 0.0
```

When I process this data :

```py
x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=(1,24))
x.dtype.is_floating # Is True

y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.reshape(y, shape=(1, 1))
y.dtype.is_floating # Is True
```

And then apply fit on my model, I get this error :

**AttributeError: 'numpy.dtype[float64]' object has no attribute 'is_floating'**

The code fails when running  keras.engine.compile_utils.match_dtype_and_rank on target data so I guess the problem comes from my *y* tensor but I do not understand why it is considered as **numpy.dtype[float64]**.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have larger float values in the x array which is taken as float64. However I tried the same code with TF 2.9 in Google Colab and it does not show any error.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
x=np.arange(0.0, 24.0)
print(x)
#x = [...] # Array of 24 floats
y = 0.0
print(y)

x = tf.convert_to_tensor(x, dtype=tf.float64) #try using float64 in place of float32
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=(1,24))

x.dtype.is_floating # Is True
```

Output:

```
[ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 15. 16. 17.
 18. 19. 20. 21. 22. 23.]
0.0
True
```

and for the `y` value

```
y = tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=tf.float64)
y = tf.reshape(y, shape=(1, 1))

y.dtype.is_floating # Is True
```

Output:

```
True
```

Let us know if the issue still persists with some more code to replicate the error. Thank you.